# Database - Lossless Join Decomposition Criteria

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless-Join_Decomposition), it says:

> The decomposition is a lossless-join decomposition of R if at least one of the following functional dependencies are in F+ (where F+ stands for the closure for every attribute or attribute sets in F):
>    R1 ∩ R2 → R1 or R1 ∩ R2 → R2

Unfortunately, I do not understand this criteria. It is known that the decomposition is lossless if the join of R1 and R2 is R, but how is this derivable from the criteria above?

Answer (score 0):

That Wikipedia article is a mess.

A decomposition is lossless if and only if the components (which are projections of the original) join back to it.

The stuff you quote is not a definition of lossless decomposition. It is a sufficient condition for showing that a decomposition is lossless given some functional dependencies that hold in the original. If the condition is met then the join is lossless. It's not a *necessary* condition.

Some university html slides:

[Decomposition](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter7/node4.html)

> 10 We'll make a more formal definition of lossless-join: [...]
>   11 In other words, a lossless-join decomposition is one in which, for any legal relation r, if we decompose r and then "recompose" r, we get what we started with--no more and no less.

A *useful sufficient condition for* [Lossless-Join Decomposition](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter7/node7.html#SECTION00731100000000000000) *during* [Normalization Using Functional Dependencies](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter7/node5.html)

> Let R be a relation schema.
>   Let F be a set of functional dependencies on R.
>   Let R1 and R2 form a decomposition of R.
>   The decomposition is a lossless-join decomposition of R if at least one of the following functional dependencies are in F+:
>   1 R1 ∩ R2 → R1
>   2 R1 ∩ R2 → R2

The idea behind knowing that sufficient condition is that you just have to show something about the set of shared attributes & some functional dependencies to know the components join to the original and (equivalently) are a lossless decomposition.

> Why is this true? Simply put, it ensures that the attributes involved in the natural join (R1 ∩ R2) are a candidate key for at least one of the two relations.